# Как сделать чтобы после удачной отправки формы перекидывало на главную страницу (с корректеровкой моего кода)

Tags: php

```
<?php
require "db.php";
?>
<form action="signup.php" method="POST">

    <p>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Введите почту" value="<?php echo @$data['email'];?>">
    </p>
    <?php
    $data = $_POST;
    if( isset($data['do_signup']) ) {
        $errors = array();
        if (trim($data['email']) == '')
        {
            $errors[] = "Необходимо заполнить поле";
        }
        ?>

        <?php
        if ($data['password'] == '') {
            $errors[] = "Ошибка в пароле или почте.";
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        if (R::count('users' , "email = ?" , array($data['email']))
            > 0)
        {
            $errors[] = "Такой e-mail уже зарегистрирован.<br><a href='login.php'>Авторизуйтесь</a>"." или "."<a href ='restore.php'>восстановите пароль</a>";
        }
        ?>
        <?php

        if( empty($errors) )
        {
            $user=R::dispense('users');
            $user->email = $data['email'];
            $user->password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            R::store($user);
            echo '<div style = "color:#00ff13;">Вы успешно зарегестрированы!</div>';
        }else
        {
            echo '<div style = "color:red;">'.array_shift($errors).'</div>';
        }

    }
    $dannie=['email']and['password'];
    if($dannie == 'true'){
        header("Location:index.php");
    }

    ?>
    <p>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" value="<?php echo @$data['password'];?>">
    </p>


    <p>
        <button type="submit" name="do_signup">ДАЛЕЕ</button>
    </p>


</form>
```

Comment: в `signup.php` делать редирект...

Comment: Это и есть signup.php

Comment: Можете сделать этот редирект.

Comment: `$dannie=['email']and['password']` это что такое?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['email'])){header("Location:index.php");}`

Comment: Виталий ,спасибо за совет!

Comment: u_mulder , это я переменной объединил значения password и email

Comment: Это вы написали код, но не понимаете как он работает.